# update table's column's year without changing the month and date for all rows

Tags: mysql

My table is kanaja postmeta,i hav around more than 1000 rows.

```
meta_id  post_id     meta_key        meta_value
403723   131871   _EventStartDate  2017-01-23 00:00:00
404269   131881   _EventStartDate  2017-01-03 00:00:00
404485   131883   _EventStartDate  2017-01-03 00:00:00
405271   131885   _EventStartDate  2017-12-20 00:00:00
404695   131887   _EventStartDate  2017-01-04 00:00:00
```

Where i just need to change the year from 2017 to 2018 and the date and month should be the same as before for all rows in the meta_value column.
               I have executed the following mysql query:

```
   UPDATE kanaja_wp.kanaja_postmeta
   SET meta_value = DATE_ADD('2017-01-23 00:00:00', INTERVAL 1 YEAR),
   SET meta_value = DATE_ADD('2017-02-01 00:00:00', INTERVAL 1 YEAR),
   WHERE meta_id IN (404269,404485);
```

which changes the year from 2017 to 2018 for two rows,To change the year for all 1000 rows,I should specify the meta_id and date for all 1000 rows which makes the query too long.
so can u help out with a mysql query,so that i can change only the year of all the column and the date and time should be same as before for all rows,so that   query will be smaller.I just want a query  like

```
   UPDATE kanaja_wp.kanaja_postmeta
   SET meta_value = DATE_ADD('2017-**-** 00:00:00', INTERVAL 1 YEAR),
   WHERE meta_key='_EventStartDate'
```

** specifies that the date and month which should not be changed

Comment: "I have executed the following mysql query:" Er, no you haven't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you need to do is use the column name in the `DATE_ADD()` function and remove the `WHERE` clause so it finds all rows.

```
UPDATE kanaja_wp.kanaja_postmeta
    SET meta_value = DATE_ADD(meta_value, INTERVAL 1 YEAR);
```

If you only want to change the dates where `meta_key='_EventStartDate'` then keep the where

```
UPDATE kanaja_wp.kanaja_postmeta
    SET meta_value = DATE_ADD(meta_value, INTERVAL 1 YEAR)
WHERE meta_key='_EventStartDate';
```

Comment: Hey Riggsfolly thank you very much. This is great and the solution works well.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
   UPDATE kanaja_wp.kanaja_postmeta
   SET meta_value = DATE_FORMAT(meta_value,'2018-%m-%d %T')
   WHERE meta_key='_EventStartDate';
```

Comment: hey vadzim thanks for the suggestion,I tried it but its not executing there is a error in query.

Answer (score 0):

This query works fine and it fulfilled my requirement

```
UPDATE kanaja_wp.kanaja_postmeta
SET meta_value = DATE_ADD(meta_value, INTERVAL 1 YEAR)
WHERE meta_key="_EventStartDate";
```

It works for all row names both start and End date as well.

Thanks for the answers :)

Comment: Is this not the answer I suggested?